# Netbeans, creating custom table model from drag and drop gui designer.

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have an application I use for an inventory of items, I am trying to add a JTable to a JFrame in my code. I have created an extension of the `AbstractTableModel` object called `ItemTableModel`. I have also dragged and dropped a JTable onto the designer view in netbeans for the respective JFrame, and renamed it to `m_jtTable`.

```
public class ItemTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
    Inventory inv;
    int rowCount = 0;
    int colCount = 3;

    public ItemTableModel(Inventory in)
    {
        inv = in;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() 
    {
        return inv.itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() 
    {
        return colCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) 
    {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
    {
        Item it = inv.itemsList.get(rowIndex);
        Object retO = null;
        switch(columnIndex)
        {
            case 0: retO = (Object)it.getItemNumber(); break;
            case 1: retO = (Object)it.getDescription(); break;
            case 2: retO = (Object)it.getPrice(); break;
            default: retO = (Object)new String("null"); break;
        }
        return retO;
    }
}
```

Then in a method in my JFrame I have the code below after an inventory is loaded

```
    ItemTableModel data = new ITemTableModel(this.inv);
    m_jtTable.setModel(data);
```

I have a few questions, what do I need to call to draw the table? Do I need to specify my table model to netbeans specifically? How do I specify column names? And if something changes in the inventory, how do I redraw the table to reflect this? (I plan to search the inventory and display possible results in this table by changing its `Inventory` to one with just the search matches)

Also, I don't need/want to make any cell editable, this table is just for viewing.

Comment: To answer your last question, override the `isCellEditable(int, int)` method from your `JTable` instance so that you always return `false`.

Comment: Not sure why thats down there, I've already done that in the code posted.

Answer (score 1):

> what do I need to call to draw the table?

Generally, nothing.  If the table has being added to a visible component, setting the model will automatically update the table with the contents of the model

> Do I need to specify my table model to netbeans specifically?

While you can "build" a model in the editor, generally, no.  You should simple create the model and apply it to the table within the code source, but after the `initComponent` has being called...

> How do I specify column names?

There are a couple of ways, but the easiest is to override the [`TableModel#getColumnName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnName%28int%29) method and return an appropriate name for the requested index

> And if something changes in the inventory, how do I redraw the table
>   to reflect this?

This will depend on how you model is implemented.  You could recreate the model and re-apply it to the table.

A better solution would be to provide a `add` method, to allow you to add new inventory `Item`s to the table, then raise the appropriate event using [`AbstractTableModel#fireTableRowsInserted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted(int, int)) which will cause the table to update it self.

If you want to update an existing item, you can either use the `setValueAt` method directory, or provide some means that you can tell the model that a given item has begin changed, for example `itemChanged(Item item)` which would need to find the row that the `Item` represents and fire [`AbstractTableModel#fireTableCellUpdated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableCellUpdated(int, int))

> (I plan to search the inventory and display possible results in this
>   table by changing its Inventory to one with just the search matches)

Take a look at [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

> Also, I don't need/want to make any cell editable, this table is just
>   for viewing.

You've already overridden `isCellEditable` to `return` `false`, so that should be working...

Take some time to read through [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for lots more details